# MySQL standalone database embedded in c# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, forms

Is it possible to add a mysql standalone database to a c# application(windows forms) just like sql lite?, so when it is deployed or installed on other systems,it uses a database,if yes,please where can i get it?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It is quite incompatible with MySQL design whose purpose is to centralize the database access and storage. A workaround would be to run [mysqldump and mysqlimport](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php#restore). However, all computers shall have access to an already installed MySQL server.

Comment: @Jeroen Heier, I haven't gotten a solution, i could possibly not have tried it..

Comment: Graffito- Would it allow the app have access to a database on another system?

Comment: MySQL database operations require that the other system has  access to an installed MySQL server (on the other computer or on it's network). You may then "copy" your database(s) to that server and open it.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks, i practically wanted a standalone database that i could publish all together with my c# application